# Can a Non-Deterministic Pushdown Automaton recognize $ \# a^nb^{2^n} \# $ which a TM can?

Tags: turing-machines, pushdown-automata

$ \# a^nb^{2^n} \# $

such that

• The alphabet of the machine is {, a, b, x}.

• The symbol x will never appear on the input a.

• The contents of the tape at completion may be anything.

• The head begins on the lefthand #.

• n ≥ 0.

I know that a Turing machine could recognize this language. But can a NPDA recognize this language too? I am thinking it can but I do not know how to start proving how/why?

Comment: What do you remember about grammars and machines?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this language is not a CFL.

---

**And here is a proof:**

Let's take string $w: a^mb^{2^m}$ where $m$ is constant guaranteed by [pumping lemma for CFLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages).

Then $a^{m+k_1}b^{2^m+k_2} \in L$ where $1\le k_1,k_2<m$

(cases invloving either $k_1 = 0$ or $k_2=0$ are easier.)

Now, that suggests that,

$2^{m+k_1} = 2^m + k_2$ (by defination of $L$)

$\therefore 2^m2^{k_1} = 2^m + k_2$   ....................................(1)

now, $k_1 \ge 1\implies 2^m2^{k_1} \ge 2^m + 2^m > 2^m + k_2.$

(because we have $k_1 \ge 1$ this means left side of equation $1$ will always have value $\ge 2.2^m$ but right side of equation can have maximum value of $2^m + m - 1$)

Hence this language can't be CFL.

Comment: is my understanding correct that because it is not a CFL, there doesn't exist any PDA or NPDA that can recognize the language, right?

Comment: Yes you're right.

Comment: i am starting to get it but i was confused how did you get here...
$k_1 \ge 1\implies 2^m2^{k_1} \ge 2^m + 2^m > 2^m + k_2.$
Would you mind breaking it down a bit?

Comment: sure I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Am I correct to say that this is a context-sensitive language because a TM can recognize this? If i recall correctly, neither PDA or NPDA can recognize a context-sensitive language right?

Comment: Now you just have to note that $\forall_{m>0}2.2^m \ge 2^m + m - 1$

Comment: yes, if that context sensitive language is not cfl then you can't have pda for that.

Comment: the language described above is context-sensitive right?

Comment: Yes this language is context sensitive.

Comment: is it enought to say that it is context-sensitive if it has a TM that recognizes it? 
or should I show productions?

Comment: I have seen this theorem:
If a language is context-free, then some NPDA accepts it.

But isn't it true that I cannot conclude that

I cannot have NPDA for this because it is not context-free? what theorem says that?

Comment: No, to prove a language context sensitive you have to show that there is a TM that decided it using space atmost linearly proportional to length of input.

Comment: Actually converse of statement in your last comment is also true.

Comment: so it is correct to say that 
"The language is not context-free therefore we cannot construct an NPDA that recognizes it."?

Comment: yes we can say that.

Comment: where did $2^m+m−1$ come from?

Comment: also correct me if im wrong but what I can recall with pumping lemma is the usage of $s = uvwxyz$ how is that related to this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102003/discussion-between-vimal-patel-and-bluewander).

Answer (score 1):

No pushdown automaton can recognize this language, because the language is not context-free. This can be shown using the [pumping lemma for context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) or [Parikh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem). The latter gives a particularly straightforward proof: the language is not context-free because $2^n$ cannot be written as a finite union of linear functions.

The language *is* context-sensitive. This can be seen by noting that it is possible to write a program that counts the number of a's and b's and checks whether they are correct using linear space. Such a program can be converted into a linear bounded automaton by the standard methods of transforming programs into Turing machines. Context-sensitive grammars are so powerful that it is often easier to think of them as being arbitrary programs with a linear space restriction, rather than grammars in the usual sense.

Comment: I see. I also thought so but I forgot about using the pumping lemma for this. I haven't heard about Parik's theorem though.

For the TM that recognizes this, I'm stuck with knowing how to move the tape head when it reads $b$. I am not sure how does it count $2^n$ for it to know when to move left and right.

Comment: @Andrew If you are trying to write a Turing machine that recognizes the language and you are stuck, I would suggest asking a separate question just for that. Editing your question with the additional question is probably a bad idea because it invalidates the current answers.

Comment: is this language described context sensitive?

Comment: @bluewander See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @bluewander, btw you can construct TM which given a input checks whether it has form $a^*b^*$. If yes for every $a$ it erases exactly half of $b$'s that are present. That way TM for language in question can be constructed. I haven't fully constructed that. This is just a idea which might not work.

Comment: but isn't "If yes for every a it erases exactly half of b's that are present" only works for $a^nb^{2n}$?

Comment: @bluewander No, because it would cut the number of b's in half for _each_ of the a's.